# extracting data from a IP restricted api using synapse analytics

Tags: rest, extract, azure-synapse

I'm trying to use the copy tool in azure synapse analytics to access data from the Clash Royale API at https://developer.clashroyale.com/#/ and store into the data lake. While creating the authorization token, you are only allowed to give specific IP addresses and not a range. While using synapse copy tool, synapse uses different IP address each time to extract the data and the authorization fails. What can I do to make this work.

Thanks in advance.

I thought I would create a Vnet and a public IP and route the traffic through it but couldn't figure out how to do it.

(update)
I was able to do it using a self hosted integration runtime running on a windows vm in azure.
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract data from a IP restricted Api using synapse analytics create https linked service with URL with "Anonymous" authentication as shown below:

[image]

You can use above linked service for copy the data to ADLS account. For more information you can refer [this document](https://trycatchdebug.net/news/1172890/extracting-clash-royale-data-with-synapse-analytics).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The document you referred says that clash royale API requires no authentication so anonymous will work but it won't. Clash royale API uses Bearer authentication tokens for authentication.

Comment: If you have bearer token authentication select anonymous authentication, add 'Authorization' header and add  "Bearer <AccessToken>" in the linked service and use it.